Use AWS session token created by serviceaccount to authenticate Spark app against s3
I am trying to run a Spark application on kubernetes which will then run on a small YARN cluster, am not that far yet.
I configure spark via configuration file in a configmap
The Spark app should use an AWS S3 bucket as default FS.
In the kubernetes deployment i use a service-account which points to a role ARN
The deployment goes fine as i see the following env vars:
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=.....
AWS_REGION=.....
AWS_ROLE_ARN=......
AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=/var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
AWS_STS_REGIONAL_ENDPOINTS=regional

Now, i would like Spark to use this session token stored in the file and the role name 
I am using the TemporaryCredentialsProvider but i cant find a way to pass the session token, i am trying:
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.session.token.file: /var/run/secrets/eks.amazonaws.com/serviceaccount/token
But this wont work, i get:
No AWS Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider : org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.CredentialInitializationException: Access key, secret key or session token is unset
How can i pass the token? any tip or alternative?

Try chaining with a  WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.
WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider awsCredentialProvider = WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider.builder()
        .roleArn(System.getenv("AWS_ROLE_ARN"))
        .roleSessionName(System.getenv("AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME"))
        .webIdentityTokenFile(System.getenv("AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE"))
        .build();


I found the answer.
I am using hadoop-aws library version 3.2.0, which uses AWS SDK version 1, that SDK does not contain WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider, i should upgrade to 3.4.0
